# Changing the order of a button and a textview crashes my app

Tags: android, android-layout, button, textview

I'm new to Android development and I have this strange problem.. Depending on the order of my layout the app works perfectly or just crashes before it's opened.

My java code:

```
package com.exmple.helloandroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

            // According to logcat. Below is the error line
    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(HelloAndroid.this, "ImageButton clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
    });
}
}
```

And the layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/text1" /> 

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/text1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the string XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="text1">This is the first text!</string>
<string name="text2">This is the second text!</string>
<string name="app_name">Hello, Android</string>

</resources>
```

Problem: If I move the textview above the button the program crashes. I can't see why this happens.

So: Am I retarded or what's the problem?

=============================
I have test the problem and yes there is issue, Here is lgocat

```
02-02 02:33:00.433: E/AndroidRuntime(2729): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-02 02:33:00.433: E/AndroidRuntime(2729): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.android.testing/com.my.android.testing.HelloAndroid}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
02-02 02:33:00.433: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
02-02 02:33:00.433: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-02 02:33:00.433: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-02 02:33:00.433: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-02 02:33:00.433: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-02 02:33:00.433: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-02 02:33:00.433: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-02 02:33:00.433: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 02:33:00.433: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-02 02:33:00.433: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-02 02:33:00.433: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-02 02:33:00.433: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-02 02:33:00.433: E/AndroidRuntime(2729): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
02-02 02:33:00.433: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):     at com.my.android.testing.TestAndActivity.onCreate(HelloAndroid.java:16)
02-02 02:33:00.433: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-02 02:33:00.433: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-02 02:33:00.433: E/AndroidRuntime(2729):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: clean your entire project and build again! hope it will fix

Comment: Please share your logcat. When application crash.

Comment: Hmm, cleaning and rebuilding works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

clean your project will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I run your code and you are correct I was giving and exception it we move TextView before the button. It was strange. But I found that it was actully some id issue. As I change the Id after moving the TextView to up and its working. But I don't a reason for that.

May Be some one batter know. But you can also try by chaining id of views.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_id_text_my"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_id_btn_my"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and also in Activity code.

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_id_btn_my);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                            Toast.makeText(TestAndActivity.this, "ImageButton clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
        });
```

Also don't forget to clean and build your project

Answer (score 0):

*You need to be careful* when moving the position of a TextView. If you do not change the ID of the TextView after moving it some place else, it is likely that it can crash your app.

I have no idea why this should happen, but changing the id solves this crashing issue.